# How can I extract a number from a string if it's next to a percent symbol?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large amount of strings I need to parse, and I want to extract numbers from them when they are next to a percent symbol, and only if they are next to a percent symbol, else returning an empty string.  And example string would be

> "43-20If you can find a way through the river of magma, I calculate a 60% chance you will arrive at one of the sources of sacred power."

And I would want to extract only the 60.  I believe the answer to my problem involves regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a regex that will find continuous digits before a percentage sign.

```
string text = "43-20If you can find a way through the river of magma, I calculate a 60% chance you will arrive at one of the sources of sacred power. Here's another: 100%.";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(\d+)%"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: +0: You need to add capture `(\d+)%` - right now it finds `60%`, not `60`.

Comment: Sorry I pasted an old version of the code sample :) Updated. The `Groups` property of the `match` contains the entire matched regex, then an entry for every captured group. Here, the first capture group is (\d+) (1+ digits) and is accessed by `match.Groups[1]`.

Comment: It's fine, I managed to get it working by using some other code to extract the % symbol.

Comment: How about 60.5 or 60.112 ? Decimal places?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to extract the value and not only check if there is a match, then I'd use this regex:

```
(?<num>\d+)(?:\%)
```

Then you can get the number by:

```
string number = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<num>\d+)(?:\%)").Groups["num"].Value;
```

Cheers

EDIT: This is called a "named capturing group", versus the second one for the % sign which is a non-capturing group.

Comment: If string contains more than one number then your solution will not work. it will retrieve only one value.

Comment: @SpiderCode you can still iterate over it with a `foreach` and it will print out all of the matches

Answer (score 1):

Just this regular expression will be enough  `(\d+)%`

See here [Regex sample Test](http://regex101.com/r/oT7zM5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
var numbers = Regex.Matches(text, @"\d+(?=%)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

The regex (see [its demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%25%29&i=43-20If%20you%20can%20find%20a%20way%20through%20the%20river%20of%20magma%2C%20I%20calculate%20a%2060%25%20chance%20you%20will%20arrive%20at%20one%20of%20the%20sources%20of%20sacred%20power.%20Here%27s%20another%3A%20100%25.)) matches

- `\d+` - one or more Unicode digits (use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` to only match ASCII digits)
- `(?=%)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a `%` char.

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/nAq1KJ):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "43-20If you can find a way through the river of magma, I calculate a 60% chance you will arrive at one of the sources of sacred power. Here's another: 100%.";
        var numbers = Regex.Matches(text, @"\d+(?=%)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", numbers)}]");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[60, 100]
```